# How to get the console window bigger?

Tags: c, windows-10

This code works well to **reduce** the width of the terminal window to 50 pts:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
HANDLE wHnd;    // Handle to write to the console.
HANDLE rHnd;    // Handle to read from the console.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Set up the handles for reading/writing:
    wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    rHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    // Change the window title:
    SetConsoleTitle("Test");
    // Set up the required window size:
    SMALL_RECT windowSize = {0, 0, 50, 10};
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHnd, 1, &windowSize);
    // Change the console window size:
        // Create a COORD to hold the buffer size:
    COORD bufferSize = {10, 10};
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(wHnd, bufferSize);
    // Exit
    return 0;
}
```

But if I want to **enlarge** the window to a width of 120 pts it doesn't work:

```
SMALL_RECT windowSize = {0, 0, 120, 10}
```

How can I solve this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You might like to look at the console function [GetLargestConsoleWindowSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getlargestconsolewindowsize). You might have to increase the buffer size and text dimensions too. I can't *drag* my default console window any wider. It will drag narrower and adds a scroll bar, and it will go deeper because there is enough buffer space.